# Multiple inputs in a single textbox

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, textbox, backend

How to make multiple inputs fit in a single line textbox using VB.Net? For Example, two string inputs in a single textbox with a delimiter like ";" in between and getting the results from both string inputs within the single line textbox.

Comment: A `TextBox` contains a single `String`. That's it, that's all. If what you want to do is split that `String` on a specific delimiter then that's what you should be researching. That has nothing to do with `TextBoxes`. A `String` is a `String`.

Comment: Agreed with @jmcilhinney! You might wanna learn more regarding the `.split` function maybe? http://vb.net-informations.com/string/vb.net_String_Split.htm

Comment: So you want to fill the Textbox from two (or more) Input sources by concatenating them with a delimiter and later parse out the value on a given position? Something like a oneliner represantion of a List(Of string)?

Comment: Or set TextBox `Multiline` to `True`, and then use `TextBox.Lines` to get multiline inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Example of input: **a;b;c;d;e**

You can do something like this:

```
Private Sub BtnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim inputValues = txtInput.Text.Split(";"c)
    Dim result = ""

    For Each value In inputValues
        result &= value & vbNewLine
    Next

    MessageBox.Show(result)
    ' a
    ' b
    ' c
    ' d
    ' e
End Sub
```

Before the edited answer this line was like this:

```
Dim inputValues = txtInput.Text.Split(";")
```

This only works if you have **Option Strict Off** like @jmcilhinney said

Comment: For the record, that code would not compile with `Option Strict On` and you should pretty much always have `Option Strict On`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for your tip! I didn't know about it and I've fixed the answer

Comment: Turn the `Option Strict On` at project level so it's on everywhere and not just the class you're in.

Comment: Also from the Tools menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults set Option Strict On for all future vb.net projects.

Comment: Since this only works with Option Strict Off - don't do it.